# How to convert HMAC Hash from python to node.js

Tags: python, node.js, hmac

I want to convert this snippet to Nodejs.

```
import urllib.request
import base64
import hmac

signature = hmac.new(SECRETKEY.encode("utf-8"), my_string.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()
urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signature))
```

How Can I do that to get exactly the same result? 
I try this But it's wrong:

```
const Base64 = require('crypto-js/enc-base64');
const hmacSHA256  = require('crypto-js/hmac-sha256');

let signature = hmacSHA256(utf8.encode(my_string), utf8.encode(SECRETKEY));
signature = Base64.stringify(signature);
```

Answer (score 2):

With NodeJS the *crypto* module can be used to generate the HMAC.

URL encoding is possible e.g. with `encodeURIComponent()`. Note that [`urllib.parse.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) does not URL encode `/` by default, so only `+` and `=` are URL encoded in a Base64 encoded string. On the other hand, [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#description) encodes all three special characters.
If this behavior is to be maintained in the NodeJS code, `/` must be URL-decoded back when `encodeURIComponent()` is applied (e.g. via a regular expression).
Alternatively, instead of `encodeURIComponent()`, only `+` and `=` could be URL encoded *directly* using regular expressions.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

var SECRETKEY = 'SECRETKEY'
var my_string = 'my_string';
var b64Hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRETKEY).update(my_string).digest('base64');
var urlB64Hmac = encodeURIComponent(b64Hmac).replace(/%2F/g, "/"); // Remove replace() if / may also be URL-encoded...
console.log(urlB64Hmac); // aB3nu4l%2BN2jf2Z9ybad6vAPVEE8JbHlya/NYlKyJLsM%3D
```

---

Alternatively, the CryptoJS library can be used as in your sample code:

```js
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')

var SECRETKEY = 'SECRETKEY'
var my_string = 'my_string';
var b64Hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(my_string, SECRETKEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var urlB64Hmac = encodeURIComponent(b64Hmac).replace(/%2F/g, "/");
console.log(urlB64Hmac); // aB3nu4l%2BN2jf2Z9ybad6vAPVEE8JbHlya/NYlKyJLsM%3D
```

However, the advantage of the *crypto* module over the CryptoJS library is that no additional dependency is needed.